# I am not able to get Authorization code while hitting url for microsoft Graph?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

The main point of my POC is to send Mail using Microsoft Graph Api In Java.
I have followed this below Github repo steps each and I am able to build the code successfully:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-java-connect-sample

According to the steps mentioned in the Repo , I should get Authorization code in URL, 
But I am unable to get the Authorization code.

I made few changes in the code ,

1. First , I replace the CLIENT_ID value as per my application client id's.
2. Secondly also change the redirect URL in Constants.java. In the Repo, 
   redirect url is mentioned as 
   "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient". But As I am 
   using organizational account, I have mentioned my application(web service) 
   redirect url.
3. Also one more change which i made is in `MicrosoftAzureAD20Api.java` , I 
   replaced the `getAccessTokenEndpoint() and getAuthorizationBaseUrl()` URL's 
   as per my application.

After running the code , it ran without error , I printed the authorization URL in console as well, but I am not getting authorization code in URL(which I printed in my console).
The expected url (acc to github) is something like :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?code={IAQABAAIAAABHh4kmS_aKT5XrjzxRAtHz5S...p7OoAFPmGPqIq-1_bMCAA}&session_state=dd64ce71-4424-494b-8818-be9a99ca0798
```

But the URL which I am getting is something like below :

```
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={{ClientId}}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&scope=Files.ReadWrite%20openid%20User.Read%20Mail.Send%20Mail.ReadWrite
```

As comparison in both url , code is missing in second one.(Which I need to pass on further)

Please help me out.

Comment: Could you please ad the link to the repo/tutorial you referring ?

Comment: @Thomas I have edited the post with the Git repo link

Comment: @nikitakakraniya Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you got is an authorization url. The command line interface opens a browser window on the Azure Active Directory authorization endpoint. You need to enter your user name and password to authenticate.

[image]

When you are authenticated, you're taken to an authorization window for the app. Click the Ok button on the authorization window. Then you will get the code.

[image]